# Install vuex without npm or yarn?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Hey I want to install vuex in my Vue3 project. Because of several reasons I have no possibility to install it with npm or yarn. I already googled for solutions but it seems like there aren't any. Had someone of you maybe the same problem or an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Vuex provides CDN build, as it's said in the answer. You will naturally have problems with third-party Vue libs this way. A lot of them assume that you build the app with Vue CLI or else. You won't be able to use them.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use with by loading it from a "CDN" as below

```
https://unpkg.com/vuex@4
```

Unpkg.com provides NPM-based CDN links. The above link will always point to the latest release on NPM. You can also use a specific version/tag via URLs like `https://unpkg.com/vuex@4.0.0/dist/vuex.global.js`

For more info refer to [installation section](https://vuex.vuejs.org/installation.html#direct-download-cdn) of Vuex docs